# Why does tone function from arduino does not work in RTOS?

Tags: c++, arduino, rtos

I am trying to output a song using the Piezoelectric buzzer on my Arduino. Running the code without RTOS functionalities works well, however, when i place the code into an RTOS task, the buzzer does not work. I am buzzled by this.

Running the code without RTOS Task function works but when implemented with RTOS, it doesn't work. It seems like the tone() function does not execute.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <task.h>

//Tones
#define  d     294    // 294 Hz
#define  e     329    // 329 Hz
#define  fSharp    370    // 369.994 Hz
#define  g     392    // 392 Hz
// Define a special note, 'R', to represent a rest
#define  R     000
#define babySharkOutput 11


int babyShark[] = {       //Note of the song, 0 is a rest/pulse
        d, e, g, g, g, g, g, g,
        d, e, g, g, g, g, g, g,
        d, e, g, g, g, g, g, g,
        g, g, fSharp, R
};

int babySharkDuration[] = {
        400, 200, 50, 50, 75, 50, 50, 75,
        400, 200, 50, 50, 75, 50, 50, 75,
        400, 200, 50, 50, 75, 50, 50, 75,
        75, 75, 250, 1000
};

int babySharkNotePause[] = {
        50, 60, 25, 20, 25, 15, 25, 40,
        50, 60, 25, 20, 25, 15, 25, 40,
        50, 60, 25, 20, 25, 15, 25, 40,
        30, 20, 50, 200
};

void songTask(void *p) {
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime = 0 ;
    const TickType_t xPeriod = pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000);
    while(1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i ++){
            tone(babySharkOutput, babyShark[i], babySharkDuration[i]);
            int songDelay = babySharkNotePause[i] * songSpeed;
            vTaskDelay(songDelay);
        }
        vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, xPeriod);
    }
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(babySharkOutput, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    xTaskCreate(songTask, "songTask", STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

Hmm I expected this would run well because it can be run without the RTOS features, but there's something wrong here and I can't figure it out.

Comment: What hardware are you running it on? I bet it’s not the AVR Arduino, and the Arduino-compatibility layer for your platform is not meant to be used together with the RTOS: use one or the other, not both. You’ll have to re-implement the tone function, perhaps by starting from the source code of the Arduino library you use – it should be included with the dev kit you use.

Comment: I am running on Arduino Uno, included with FreeRTOS libraries, written on Eclipse with AVRdude installed. I guess you are right because I mixed both Arduino library tone function with FreeRTOS code. I guess I will have to take a look at the source code of the tone function. Thanks

Comment: FreeRTOS is extremely resource constrained on the UNO. You have to perform extensive error checking since API calls may fail due to resource exhaustion: they may do so on a system of any size and you should be doing error checking anyway, so be sure that you check all API return values for errors! You do no error checking: you don’t even know that your task runs at all!!

Comment: LOL CG2271 HAHAHA

Comment: @MiDaa HAHAHA! YEAA